# Mutex and block scope

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

Having a mutex in code:

```
class Bank{
public:
    Bank():counter(0){};
    void addBankAccount(){
        unique_lock<mutex>  m ( g_Mtx );
        for( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            counter++;
        }
    }

    int getCounter(){
        return counter;
    }

private:
    int counter;
    mutex g_Mtx;
};


int calculate(){
    Bank b;
    thread t1(&Bank::addBankAccount,&b);
    thread t2(&Bank::addBankAccount,&b);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    if( b.getCounter() != 2000)
        cout << "Error value is " << b.getCounter() << endl;
}

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        calculate();
    return 0;
}
```

the mutex itself is neccessery , in order to maintain right result.
If i am not mistaken without mutex it would result in something:

```
      THREAD 1                           |              THREAD 2
                                         | 
 1)  load value of counter in register   |  2) load value of counter in register
     value in register is 0              |     value in register is 0

 3)   increment register( value is 1)    |  4)    increment register( value is 1)

4) update variable, value of             |  5) update variable, value of
   counter is set to 1                          again counter is set to 1
```

( marking 1)... 5) should indicate in what order can be instruction processed by computer ) Thus some increments are omitted. But my question is about mutex itself.

When two threads are running for example same function

```
void addBankAccount(){
    unique_lock<mutex>  m ( g_Mtx );
    for( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        counter++;
    }
}
```

In my undertanding , when mutex is declared  and lock is being locked , the thread that wants to acces to data that is held in lock "pauses" and "resumes" when the lock is unlocked and it can access the data ( the threads that wants to use that data are in queue ). But what happens when mutex is in another block scope? For example :

```
    void addBankAccount(){
        {
           unique_lock<mutex>  m ( g_Mtx );
           for( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
             counter++;
        }
         // some other piece of code
    }
```

Would this change something? I have seen this usage and i do not see how it differs from original declaration of the function. When thread want to access data that are locked , does it "pauses" whole thread , or does it "pauses" just the block scope , so in this case it would jumpe to

```
 // some other piece of code
```

and when lock is unlocked it jumps back in loop inside scope?

I have read quite a few articles about mutex but i am still confused with this.

And ofc , my understanding of mutex can be wrong.

All explanations are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: *"Would this change something?"* That rather depends on what "some other piece of code" is doing, and in particular whether it accesses any shared state. It doesn't change anything with respect to `counter`-incrementing loop above it, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: The thread does not "pause a piece of code". The thread "pauses" itself - the constructor of `unique_lock` calls `g_Mtx.lock()`, which simply doesn't return until the lock is obtained. The role of the block is to establish scope for `m` - at the end of the block, it goes out of scope, its destructor runs and calls `g_Mtx.unlock()`, possibly giving another thread a chance.

Comment: So basicly , if "some other piece of code" somehow manipulated with data that is in lock it would not execute but when it does not it would, and only when lock is in another block code? ... I see your second answer and this quite confused me ( when i consider your first answer).

Comment: You seem to have a wrong conceptual model of how locks work. I don't really understand how you are thinking of them, so it's difficult for me to correct your misunderstanding. I wonder if it would help if you replace `unique_lock<mutex>  m ( g_Mtx );` line with its actual effect - namely, calling `g_Mtx.lock()` explicitly in place of that line, and `g_Mtx.unlock()` right before the closing brace of the block containing that line.

Comment: To simplify my understanding of conceptual model of locks , you can imagine class , with some bool property that is set to true or false , and data that is being locked. if you want to access data you first need to check if lock is set to false , if not , u have to keep checking it until it is set to false and u can access the data.

Comment: Right. So then, where is all this "jumping" come from that you are talking about? No such thing is happening. "Some other piece of code" always executes after the block with the loop.

Comment: Indeed that what confuses me , i do not see the point of declaring the mutex inside another block scope , that what confuses me :)

Comment: It's not the mutex that's declared inside the scope, but an instance of `unique_lock<mutex>`. This is a simple class - roughly, its constructor takes a mutex as a parameter and calls `lock()` on it, and its destructor calls `unlock()` on the same mutex. Like any local variable, this instance of `unique_lock` is destroyed when it goes out of scope - at the end of the block in which it's declared. Nesting it in an extra block limits its scope, so it gets destroyed earlier (than it would have been if it were at the function scope).

Comment: In other words, when you have `{unique_lock<mutex>  m ( g_Mtx ); DoSomething();} DoSomethingElse();`, it's equivalent to `g_Mtx.lock(); DoSomething(); g_Mtx.unlock(); DoSomethingElse();`. On the other hand, without the extra block, `unique_lock<mutex>  m ( g_Mtx ); DoSomething(); DoSomethingElse();` is equivalent to `g_Mtx.lock(); DoSomething(); DoSomethingElse(); g_Mtx.unlock();`. Do you see the difference?

Comment: Oh now i get it ... but i cant mark your answer as accepted :/

Answer (score 1):

In your example, there is no difference.  The reason to embed the lock in an inner block, is so that the mutex can be released early..

```
void addBankAccount(){
    int count_save;
    {
       unique_lock<mutex>  m ( g_Mtx );
       for( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
         counter++;
       }
       count_save = counter;
     }  // mutex will be released here

     // Still inside addBankAccount, but now it's safe to do IO
     std::cout << "Bank account is now" << count_saved;
}
```

You often find you want to release a mutex, and then do some other processing.  For example, IO is slow, and involves obtaining other locks; it's a good idea not to do it while holding a mutex.

Notice that in the example, `count_save` is a local variable and as such is private to the thread - it is not part of the shared state being protected by the mutex.  It is essential not to touch any of the shared state once the mutex has been released.

Note also, that because of the lack of synchronization, the account state can have changed before the output occurs.  In fact, there is no guarantee that the output from an earlier change will occur before the output from a later change.  (As such, this may not have been a particularly good example!)

Comment: Why is it safe to print count_saved? After lock is released the other thread can access the data so you are not quaranteed that right before it is printed other thread didnt change the data, or am i wrong?

Comment: @trolkura `count_save` is a local variable, not shared with any other thread, so it doesn't need to be accessed under the lock. But yes, it is possible that by the time the line is printed, the account balance has already changed.

Comment: oh , but if it was shared variable , it wouldnt quarantee  that any other thread didnt change it right? ..

Comment: @trolkura: Yes, once the lock is released you must ensure you don't touch any variables that are protected by the lock.

Comment: @trolkura If it were a shared variable, then accessing it at the same time another thread modifies it would be a data race, which exhibits undefined behavior. A program containing undefined behavior can do anything at all - there are no guarantees about its behavior. See also: [nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for help , now i understand it :)